# first python program need a bit of help writing to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a small program that I'm trying to create to get ip addresses from an sqlite db and run the whois command on and write it to a data file.

```
import sqlite3
import os
v_path = os.path.abspath('') 
v_db = os.path.abspath("../")+"/logsql.sqlite"
v_ip = v_path+"/Whois.Resources/Who.IP.txt"
print v_ip
try:
    f1 = open(v_db)
    f2 = open(v_ip, "w")
    conn = sqlite3.connect(v_db)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("select remote_host from connections group by remote_host;")
    for row in c:
        print row
        #p.write("sts")
    c.close()   
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
except IOError as e:
   print 'Oh dear, shit just hit the fan.'
```

The output looks like this

```
bash$ python WhoIs.Program.py 
/Users/frankwiebenga/Documents/Spring 2012/Malware/WhoIs/Whois.Resources/Who.IP.txt
Oh dear, shit just hit the fan.
```

The issue is opening v_ip, the v_db opens fine. The file is there

```
bash$ pwd
/Users/frankwiebenga/Documents/Spring 2012/Malware/WhoIs/WhoIs.Resources
bash$ ls
Who.IP.txt
frank-wiebengas-macbook-pro:WhoIs.Resources frankwiebenga$
```

The directory structure is

```
logsql WhoIs{directory}
____________
WhoIs.Program.py WhoIs.Resources{directory}
____________
Who.IP.txt
```

Comment: try to put `print( sys.exc_info()[1] )` in your except clause to see what the error actually is. (your custom message is useless for debugging.)

Comment: You exception handler is hardly helpful, try removing it (or just add `raise` below your funny line).

Comment: Not catching the exception might give you more information about the error.

Comment: re: 'custom message/funny line', I would recommend replacing it with something that you will find useful (and less offensive to your customer).  You'll find that sort of stuff manages to find it's way out into the real world quite frequently.

Comment: I'm also going to suggest losing the crude humor. If you get into that habit, you'll find yourself someday in a very embarassing spot, and it might cost you a job. It's just not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Whois.Resources` should be `WhoIs.Resources`. Linux is case sensitive.

P.S. Thanks for including enough information in your question to figure this out. It's rare for that to happen.

Comment: as the comments on the question point out, it would have been much easier if we have a 'No such file or directory' message to work with; good catch though!